# Unexpected grepl behavior: return false by certain strings

Tags: r, regex

I've stange experience with grepl (and grep too)

```
> grepl("[:alpha:]","spring")
[1] TRUE
> grepl("[:alpha:]","svg")
[1] FALSE

> grep("[:alpha:]","spring")
[1] 1
> grep("[:alpha:]","svg")
integer(0)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Do you mean `grepl("[[:alpha:]]","svg")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
grepl("[[:alpha:]]","spring")
[1] TRUE
grepl("[[:alpha:]]","svd")
[1] TRUE
```